# How to do pagination based on page numbers using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In MS documentation about [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) there is a certain way for paginating the resources. Instead of using skiptoken to reach next page of resources, want to paginate **user resources** based on page numbers. So that i don't have to use skip token 5 times to reach 6th page of resources and reach it directly.

How can i do this using MS Graph API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination based on the page number is not supported on `user` resource.

Some resources support `$skip` query parameter which allows to set the number of items to skip at the start of a collection but `$skip` parameter is not supported by the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

Comment: Thank you, but is there any solution or parameter i can use in order to achieve page based direct pagination?

Comment: Not at the moment as far as I know. This limitation is due to the way the data is stored and replicated behind the scenes. As HTTP requests are stateless, you can fall on any replica between two subsequent requests, which can have really different replication states. The skiptoken contains a watermark to mitigate that. Otherwise paging would be unusable as the global dataset (all pages together) might change between the first and the last page. If this is something you feel should be added, don't hesitate to post/upvote on https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com